# point a String to a list of constants and get the constant value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to know how is possible to point a String to a list of constants and get the constant value.
I have a list of hundreds constants declared in .m as follow:

```
NSString *const onenumber = @"2.58";
NSString *const twonumber = @"3.58";
NSString *const threenumber = @"2.72";
// and so on...
```

Below I have "myString" value that give me the same name of one of the constants:

```
NSString *myString= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@number", mynumber]; //mynumber isEqual to one,two,three etc...
```

How can I displayed the value of my number specified in the constant in a label without to use hundreds of if statements?

```
result.text= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", ????? ];
```

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Put the constants in a dictionary instead of declaring individual variables for each constant.

Comment: Or even an NSArray if myNumber is just an integer from 0 to n (ie, no gaps in the range)

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your answer. It will help me a lot to use NSDictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy, I think your comment helped questioner to solve his problem. It would be great if you can give an answer to this question so the questioner can accept this.